# Changing the parent of an `option` in `select` removes events

Tags: jquery, html

I have two `select` lists.
I populate the first through jquery (1.9.X) and I am adding a `dblclick` event to each `option` item.

The expected behaviour is : *"When a user Double Click an Item to List1, the item should 'jump' to List2 and vise-versa"*

The problem is that when an item 'jumps' to List2, the event seems to de-bind it self.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/athafoud/7buedvnd/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are expecting the double-click handler to survive a `remove` and `append`, don't. `remove()` will disconnect any event handlers too.

Although you can fix this by simply removing the `remove()`s (as @Arun P Johny suggests), you are better off using delegated handlers on the lists instead: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/j08LLpqe/2/

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var item = $('<option></option>').attr('value', i).html(i);
    $('#list1').append(item);
}
$('#list1,#list2').on('dblclick', 'option', function (event) {
    if ($(this).closest('#list1').length > 0) {
        console.log('onList1');
        // Item resides on the left list
        $(this).remove().appendTo("#list2");
    } else {
        console.log('onList2');
        // Item resides on the right list
        $(this).remove().appendTo("#list1");
    }
});
```

These work by listening for the event to bubble up to the target elements (your lists) then applying the jQuery selector *at event time*, then applying the function *to the `option` that caused the event*. The upshot being that they can move between lists dynamically and you don't need separate handlers.

Update. You can simplify your "list check" using `has()` and `remove() is redundant as append will move an element in the DOM`:

```
if ($('#list1').has(this).length) {
```

e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/j08LLpqe/5/

You can of course keep reducing your code, but at some point you need to decide on how readable you want it to be. e.g. this will do the same job in one line: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/j08LLpqe/7/

```
$('#list1,#list2').on('dblclick', 'option', function (event) {
    $(this).appendTo($('#list1').has(this).length ? "#list2" : "#list1");
});
```

Comment: I understood where my problem was! The second fiiddle with the `has` does not work, but I got the point.

Comment: @Athafoud: My bad (fixed). I started using it as a boolean (like `is()`). Added the missing `.length` :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is [.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) which will remove the data associated with the removed element which will cause the event to get unregistered

> In addition to the elements themselves, all bound events and jQuery
>   data associated with the elements are removed.

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var item = $('<option></option>').attr('value', i).html(i);

    // Append Event
    item.off('dblclick');
    item.on('dblclick', function(event) {
        console.log('dbClicked');
        if($(this).closest('#list1').length > 0)
        {
            console.log('onList1');
            // Item resides on the left list
            $(this).appendTo("#list2");
        }
        else
        {
            console.log('onList2');
            // Item resides on the right list
            $(this).appendTo("#list1");
        }
    });


    $('#list1').append(item);
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/juk9u81g/)

Comment: +1 This solution has the less code rewriting and better suits my particular case. I will use this but the 'accepted' goes to @TrueBlueAussie, because he were faster and his solution is more solid. Thank you!!

Comment: @Athafoud actually with delegation it is much more simpler - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/juk9u81g/2/